# How to make GREP select only numeric values?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I use the `df` command in a bash script:

```
df . -B MB | tail -1 | awk {'print $4'} | grep  .[0-9]*
```

This script returns:

```
99%
```

But I need only numbers (to make the next comparison).
If I use the `grep` regex without the dot:

```
df . -B MB | tail -1 | awk {'print $4'} | grep  .[0-9]*
```

I receive nothing.
How to fix?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you try:

```
 echo "99%" |grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

It returns:

```
99
```

---

Here's the details on the `-o` (or `--only-matching` flag) works from the [grep manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html).

> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of matching lines, with each such part on a separate output line. Output lines use the same delimiters as input, and delimiters are null bytes if -z (--null-data) is also used (see [Other Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Other-Options)).

Comment: You can also use the alias `\d` like `echo "99%" |grep -o '\d*'`

Comment: Are you sure about that @FabSa ? have you done a test? AFAK, grep default use BRE..

Comment: It works for me yes (on OsX) but maybe you need the "extended-regexp" (with `-E`)

Comment: @FabSa for gnu grep, to make `\d` effective, you need `-P`. And if there is a portable version available, use the portable one.

Answer (score 9):

`grep` will print any **lines** matching the pattern you provide. If you only want to print the part of the line that matches the pattern, you can pass the **-o** option:

> **-o, --only-matching**
>   Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

Like this:

```
echo 'Here is a line mentioning 99% somewhere' | grep -o '[0-9]+'
```

Comment: This won't work on all versions/builds of grep.
You will need -P or -E 
So this will work

    echo 'Here is a line mentioning 99% somewhere' | grep -oP '[0-9]+'

Or
    echo 'Here is a line mentioning 99% somewhere' | grep -oP '[0-9]+'

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
df . -B MB | tail -1 | awk {'print $4'} | cut -d'%' -f1
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to used grep here, Try this:

```
df . -B MB | tail -1 | awk {'print substr($5, 1, length($5)-1)'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getPercentUsed() {
    $sys = system("df -h /dev/sda6 --output=pcent | grep -o '[0-9]*'", $val);
    return $val[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use more commands than necessary, leave away tail, grep and cut. You can do this with only (a simple) awk

PS: giving a block-size en print only de persentage is a bit silly ;-) So leave also away the "-B MB"

> df . |awk -F'[**multiple field seperators**]' '$NF=="**Last field must be exactly --> mounted patition**" {print $(NF-**number from last field**)}'

in your case, use:

```
df . |awk -F'[ %]' '$NF=="/" {print $(NF-2)}'
```

*output:* **81**

If you want to show the percent symbol, you can leave the -F'[ %]' away and your print field will move 1 field further back

```
df . |awk '$NF=="/" {print $(NF-1)}'
```

*output:* **81%**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Perl style regular expressions as well. A digit is just `\d` then.

```
grep -Po "\\d+" filename
```

**-P** Interpret PATTERNS as Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCREs).

**-o** Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.